# how to define multivariete normal distribution on sphere

Tags: probability-distributions, lie-groups, normal-distribution, lie-algebras

In Euclidean vector space, we can parameterize multivariate normal distribution by its mean vector and covariance matrix.

On a general sphere $S^n$, starting from a dirac delta and simulate the heat equation, one can also obtain an gaussian-like distribution, as answered in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90610/gaussian-distribution-on-a-2-sphere) question.

Now that I wonder if its possible to define a "spherical multivariate normal distribution". Obviously, the "mean vector" on a sphere would be an unit vector. However, how should one properly define "covariance matrix" on $S^n$?

Answer (score 1):

Take a loot at [5-parameter Fisher–Bingham distribution/Kent distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kent_distribution).